# SmartGWT ComboBoxItem - item in Combo is not marked in the pick list

Tags: smartgwt

I'm using ComboBoxItem(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.ComboBoxItem). My question is how to force it to mark, hilight selected value in a pick list? 
It is demonstrated in the SmartGWT showcase, Combo with a Label "A simple ComboBoxItem" http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category. 
'Mouse' item is in the combo, however in the pick list 'Cat' item is selected - not as I would expect - a 'Mouse'.

Thanks in advance, 
emph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. ComboBoxItem's PickList object (the drop down list), always moves its cursor (the selection marker) at the top of the list, or the first element that will be selected based on the user's input. If you want the cursor to show the selected value, use the SelectedItem instead, in the same way you use the ComboBoxItem. One drawback with this, is the fact that you can't type and have the auto-complete effect. However, if you type after you open the PickList for the SelectItem, the cursor will move to a matching option.